# Split text in column into words and print them in another column

Tags: vba, excel, split

This question seems to be asked many times, but I have some troubles with it. The task is given some number of cells in column (lets say it column A) split text in each cell (the delimiter is a space " ") and print all obtained words in another column (lets say column C).

After reading some answers I wrote the following code:

```
Sub splitting()

Dim tmp As Collection
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = 0 To 3
   tmp.Add split(Cells(i + 1, 1).Value, " ")
Next i

For j = 0 To tmp.Count
    Cells(j + 1, 3).Value = tmp(j)
Next j

End Sub
```

Here I use collection instead of array to have an ability of dynamical rearranging (add new item each time in a loop). I also suppose that the text is only in the first four rows just to test.

It gives me an error

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable is not set

What am I doing wrong and how should I do it in a proper way?

Comment: Maybe you forgot about `Set tmp = new collection` ?

Comment: which line gives you the error

Comment: Anyway, in second loop you're trying to give array to a single-cell value. What do you expect here? You need to give array to a double-cell range and `transpose` array first to fit in vertical dimension!

Comment: @CommonSense, thanks, I added Set tmp = new collection. Now I have an error 'Run time error 9: Subscript out of range' in the string inside second loop. It prints me only first words from corresponding cells and gives this error. In the second loop I expect that after new cell was splitted into words that were added in collection it will assign cell values to this words (print each new word in a new row).

Comment: Collection index starts at 1, not 0. The error is here: `tmp(j)`

Comment: Start your loop at 1 and remove the +1. All will be sorted.

Comment: @KostasK, thank you very much, I fixed it, but also remarked another error -- there are only first words from corresponding cells in collection. What should I do to include all words from splitted cells in it?

Comment: Each item in the collection contains a list, therefore besides looping through the collection, you also need an inner loop to get the items of the list.

Comment: @KostasK., oh, I understood. I declared [code]v As Variant[/code] and modified the second loop to

[code]For j = 1 To tmp.Count
    For Each v In tmp(j)
        Cells(j, 3).Value = v
    Next v
Next j[/code]

The question is how should I specify looping range instead of tmp.Count? Suppose that each cell may contain a different number of words, so be splitted into lists of different lengths. For range to tmp.Count the output is the last words from each cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize all the issues noted in comments, see the example below:

Input:

```
one two three four five 
six seven eight nine 
ten eleven twelve
```

```
Sub splitting()

    Dim tmp As Collection
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

    Set tmp = New Collection

    For i = 1 To 3
       tmp.Add Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")
    Next i

    For j = 1 To tmp.Count
        For k = 0 To UBound(tmp(j))
            Debug.Print tmp(j)(k)
        Next k
    Next j
End Sub
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
eleven
twelve
```

Answer (score -2):

Your collection is declared but not initialized. Try changing to:

```
Dim tmp As New Collection
```

Comment: This is called auto-instancing and should be avoided. The object isn't really created, but creation occurs when it is first encountered in code.